# Passing the function *cmp(const *void, const *void) as a parameter in C and using it to create a queue?

Tags: c, queue

I have an assignment from a professor that I don't fully understand.  This is our specified function header:

```
PQueue createQueue( int (*cmp)(const void*a, const void*b) ) {
```

I can't find the documentation for cmp to understand what the function itself does; what does it do?

And beyond that, how can I refer to it within createQueue when I write the code to create the queue?

Comment: You refer to the function parameter by its *name*, namely `cmp`.

Comment: For example, such as by comparing the priority of when it is added to the queue.

Comment: But what does this function actually do when it's referred to within the queue creation function?

Comment: The `cmp` function is a user-defined function that compares two items. Assuming that you're implementing a priority queue, your `addToQueue` function will need the `cmp` function to determine where to put a new item in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmp` is parameter of `createQueue`, it is a function pointer passed in by the caller. Typically `cmp` it will return:

- a negative integer if `*a` is less than `*b`
- 0 if `*a` is equal to `*b`
- a positive integer if `*a` is greater than `*b`

This is the convention used by the standard library [`qsort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), which sorts an array when given some comparison function.

As a concrete example, we can get the behavior

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 2;
cmp(&a, &b); // returns < 0
cmp(&b, &c); // returns 0
cmp(&b, &a); // returns > 0
```

if we define cmp as

```
int cmp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    const int * a_int_ptr = (const int *)a;
    const int * b_int_ptr = (const int *)b;

    int a_value = *a_int_ptr;
    int b_value = *b_int_ptr;

    return a_value - b_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,the **qsort** function is the algorithm of quick sort.As for the **cmp**  function ,it is used to determine your sort rule.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int cmp(const void *,const void*);
int cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}
```

This is an example of the data type of int.

```c
int cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(double*)a>*(double*)b?1:-1;
}
```

This is double.
We can create different cmp according to our data type ,such as char ,struct.
My immature answer hope will help you.

Comment: Technically, the standard `qsort` function doesn't *have* to use a classic quick sort.